# How can I set system audio + microphone as the audio input for video conference software?

Tags: audio, microphone, streaming, video-conference

I am trying to set up my audio devices in a way that I can stream a mix of my voice (internal MacBook microphone) and the Mac's system audio via a video conference software.

The software I am trying to use specifically is Microsoft Teams, but the same question could go for Skype or Zoom or any other video conference software that let's you select the audio input. I saw some online articles that suggested you create a "Multi-Output Device" in the Audio-MIDI-Setup software. But I tried that and I cannot get it to connect to Teams (i.e. I cannot select this Multi-Output Device as my "microphone" in Teams).

Does anybody know how this can be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, whenever you need to stream the audio from your PC, you only need the audio from a single programme, because otherwise also the incoming audio from your conference members in MS Teams would be streamed back to them as well. When you start screen sharing, or sharing a particular programme, there should be an option to share audio as well, at least this is how MS Skype works so I think Teams will do it similarly. So in order to share for example the audio from a video file, you can open it with whatever software you want, and then just share this software with the screen sharing option. I tried this with many different programmes and different hardware devices, and it always worked quite well, even if the video is just a random video from YouTube that I stream down over the web to my browser.

Comment: "otherwise also the incoming audio from your conference members in MS Teams would be streamed back to them as well" That's a very good point that I had not thought of. The approach you suggested does not seem to work on the MS Teams (and MS Skype) Mac software. This Teams page help page mentions that the feature exists for Windows, but is not available for Mac yet (but coming soon): https://bit.ly/3qMrH0V
As I don't know what "soon" in this context means, I will have to find another solution for now.

Comment: Oh, sorry that I couldn't help you then, I only use windows at home and at work, so I never had to deal with this problem on am Mac yet. One possibility would be to use a virtual/external soundcard that processes your system sounds, and your microphone, renders them together to a single audio track and gives this track to your external microphone input. But I don't know how to realise that. There are external USB soundcards out there, maybe you can have a look at these if they can solve your problem. Of cause you still have the problem that the sound from MS Teams goes back to the other users.